# TreeView expander click doesn't trigger SelectedItemChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

Considering the fact that there is no `SelectedItem` property to bind to when it comes to `TreeView`, I use `System.Windows.Interactivity` library by invoking a command when `SelectedItemChanged` event occurs. The problem is that the command is not executed when expander is clicked which in my case is important in later processing.

```xml
<TreeView Name="pluginsTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedPluginChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=pluginsTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type plugins:PluginBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type plugins:TabBase}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeViewItem}" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: By default, TreeView controls do not change selection when a node is expanded.

Think about how something like Windows Explorer works. You don't want to switch to a different folder just because you expanded another item in the navigation panel.

Comment: Expanding or collapsing a node does not raise selection events but raises `Expanded` or `Collapsed` events. Refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#expanding-and-collapsing-a-treeviewitem).

Comment: Why would the `SelectedItemChanged` event be raised when you don't select an item?

Comment: Well that explains everything, is there any way to make it work as I would like it to?